Difference between formatjs core and individual packages
Context: I am developing an app in React Native, with Hermes. I need to format currencies, dates, durations, etc. So far, I have imported all the polyfills for each locales I support and each formatter I need
require('@formatjs/intl-getcanonicallocales/polyfill');
require('@formatjs/intl-locale/polyfill');

require('@formatjs/intl-pluralrules/polyfill-force');
require('@formatjs/intl-pluralrules/locale-data/en.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-pluralrules/locale-data/it.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-pluralrules/locale-data/es.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-pluralrules/locale-data/pt.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-pluralrules/locale-data/de.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-pluralrules/locale-data/cs.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-displaynames/polyfill-force');
require('@formatjs/intl-displaynames/locale-data/en.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-displaynames/locale-data/it.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-displaynames/locale-data/es.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-displaynames/locale-data/pt.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-displaynames/locale-data/de.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-displaynames/locale-data/fr.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-displaynames/locale-data/cs.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT

require('@formatjs/intl-listformat/polyfill-force');
require('@formatjs/intl-listformat/locale-data/en.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-listformat/locale-data/it.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-listformat/locale-data/es.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-listformat/locale-data/pt.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-listformat/locale-data/de.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-listformat/locale-data/fr.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-listformat/locale-data/cs.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT

require('@formatjs/intl-numberformat/polyfill');
require('@formatjs/intl-numberformat/locale-data/en.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-numberformat/locale-data/it.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-numberformat/locale-data/es.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-numberformat/locale-data/pt.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-numberformat/locale-data/de.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-numberformat/locale-data/fr.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-numberformat/locale-data/cs.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT

require('@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/polyfill-force');
require('@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/locale-data/en.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/locale-data/it.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/locale-data/es.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/locale-data/pt.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/locale-data/de.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/locale-data/fr.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/locale-data/cs.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT

require('@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/polyfill-force');
require('@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/locale-data/en.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/locale-data/it.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/locale-data/es.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/locale-data/pt.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/locale-data/de.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/locale-data/fr.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT
require('@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/locale-data/cs.js'); // USE YOUR OWN LANGUAGE OR MULTIPLE IMPORTS YOU WANT TO SUPPORT

import '@formatjs/intl-durationformat/polyfill-force';

1st question: What is the difference between the core formatjs/intl lib providing methods like formatNumber, etc, and the different packages, like formatjs/intl-numberformat (I noticed that individual packages are bigger than the core lib  )
2nd question: Given the time required to init formatters instances, I saw that I should cache them. However, the caching solution leverages the core formatjs/intl package with the following https://formatjs.io/docs/intl/
import {createIntl, createIntlCache} from '@formatjs/intl'

// This is optional but highly recommended
// since it prevents memory leak
const cache = createIntlCache()

const intl = createIntl(
  {
    locale: 'fr-FR',
    messages: {},
  },
  cache
)

// Call imperatively
intl.formatNumber(20)

So, could I just use the core lib ?. If not, should I use it in combination with the individual packages ? Because, how to cache individual packages instances given the options are passed to the constructor and not the format method unlike for formatjs/intl package ?
